# Refresh rows in results window

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have some rows that all contain the same flag value from a column and they don't have anything else in common.  When I run my program, the flag is going to be updated so that re-running the query will no longer find the same rows.

Is there a way to run a query, and then later just refresh the rows as long as they are still in the results window?

Comment: I don't think you can refresh what is stored in the results window directly. A staging table could work. Use your program to insert the results into a table named tblQryResults. To refresh, update from the original query with another method, function, etc. and query tblQryResults.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  You can cut and paste what is in the results window and create inserts out of that data.  Unlike xbase solutions when you commit a delete your data is deleted.  You have to have an external copy or backup to restore from to put the data back.